# error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, web-config, connection-string

If I have my connection string in the web.config like this (added line feeds for better readability):

```
<add 
name="conn" 
connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial 
    Catalog=MyDB; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; 
    AttachDbFilename=D:\Products.mdf" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

The connection works and I can connect to the database in the database explorer.

When I specify the connectionstring in code or use ConfigurationManager to get it it doesn't work:

```
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.CommandText = "select ...";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\v11.0;"+
        "Initial Catalog=MyDB; Integrated Security=True; "+
        "MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=D:\\Products.mdf");
    command.Connection = cn;
    cn.Open();
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    SqlDataReader reader;
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    dataTable.Load(reader);
    cn.Close();
```

Getting the connection string from the web.config gives the same error:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
 ["conn"].ConnectionString;
```

The error I am getting is " System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found"

In the trace is says:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server)]

I need some help solving this, been trying to solve this for hours and any on line suggestion is that I should check network settings (doesn't apply as it's connecting to local instance of sql server express). The server name (same string works in VS Express but not in running code).

Could it be an authentication issue? And if so then why the un informative error?

Thank you for reading my post and hope you can help me with this.

Update:

I've tried the following things:

Given the group everyone full permission on the mdf and ldf files

In project properties under web I've tried running the project under VS development server and local IIS web server (is IIS Express)

No luck, still can't connect where it connects perfectly fine when copying the code to a project that has been created with "ASP.NET empty Web Application"

Comment: what is version of sql server ???

Comment: My guess is sql server express 11 (v11.0 in the connection string) in program files I've got a SQL server folder with subfolders named 8 to 11 (standard VS 2013 express install)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was related to the application not running in .net version 4.0

According to the following page:
http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012#sqlconnection

You need .net 4.0 and up to use named pipes:

> The Server=(localdb) syntax is not supported by .NET framework
>   versions before 4.0.2. However the named pipes connection will work to
>   connect pre 4.0.2 applications to LocalDB instances.

```
SqlLocalDB.exe create MyInstance
SqlLocalDB.exe start MyInstance
SqlLocalDB.exe info MyInstance
```

The info provides the named pipe then this can be used in the connection string:

```
<add name="conn" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
connectionString="Server=np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#B1704E69\tsql\query"/>
```

Comment: I have a similar problem (I get error 26 instead of 40), but I do have .NET framework 4.5 installed. I cannot access (localdb)\v.110, but I can access the db via the named pipe. What could I do?

Comment: @csima Does the connection work when you try to see the tables in the database explorer of Visula studio (express). VS uses the web.config connection to connect so if it works there but not in your application then check out Damith's answer and make sure you run your appliction with the .net 4 runtime as you can have it run with an older version.

Comment: Yes it does work in Visual Studio. My [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625151/azure-storage-emulator-cannot-connect-to-localdb) was related to the fact that the Azure emulator itself could not connect, and the same happened when I tried to establish an ODBC connection (although named pipes worked). I chose to switch to SQLEXPRESS. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 14):

You've properly escaped the db filename but not the datasource, therefore it tries to connect to a datasource named "(localdb)11.0", which (most likely) doesn't exist.

Try escaping it properly like this:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\v11.0;"+
"Initial Catalog=MyDB; Integrated Security=True; "+
"MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=D:\\Products.mdf");
```

Comment: Thank you, that did make the code work in another project. The thing I am working on doesn't have a project file so I used file => open web site. The code that works in a new web forms project doesn't in a "open web site" project (copied and pasted working code).

Comment: This problem still exist. When using a project "open web site" and adding a data connection for testing "sql server express" using the connection string mentioned above or getting it from web config I get the before mentioned error. When using the exact same connection string it works when creating a project with "empty asp.net web application" or "asp.net web forms appliction"

Comment: According to the exception details, you are using the named pipes protocol; could you switch to TCP/IP and see if it helps? See http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/24/sql-force-the-protocol-tcp-named-pipes-etc-in-your-connection-string.aspx also, did you try to connect to a different SQL Server instance?

Comment: It connects to SQL server and to the server the website uses but it will never connect to my local sql server express.

Comment: In VS in the database explorer I can browse the tables using the same connection string but the application doesn't. Copying the code and the connection string to anotehr application makes it work. Just want to set up a test db for when I work on the project locally but can't get it to work. maybe it needs driver references.

Comment: Are you sure that you fixed the escaping in all possible locations in your project? I find it strange that it would run in a different project but not this one. When the exception occurs, can you check that the connection string in the exception trace is correct?

Comment: I'm trying to add a connection to a local sql express database from an existing "project". Since the "project" doesn't have a project file I have to open it as file => open web site. From that project whatever sql express connection doesn't work. Copy the code and the connection string to a fresh project (like file => new project => asp.net empty web application works. Exactly same code exactly same connectionstring. In the "open web site" project I can browse the data in the VS data explorer so the connection string in the web.config is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using (localdb), have you tried using '.\SQLExpress;' per this page on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504.aspx)?  It uses the default instance, which may not be what you need.

it would read like so:

```
<add 
name="conn" 
connectionString="Provider=SqlClient;Data Source=.\\SQLExpress; Initial 
    Catalog=MyDB; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; 
    AttachDbFilename=D:\Products.mdf" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Daniele, tried that but same error and it stopped working in VS database explorer. The fact that it works in the VS database explorer and that the connectionstring is taken from the web config tells me that the connection string should be correct but maybe doesn't work with .net 3.5 or VS doesn't start some service when it's a web site project or ...

Comment: Daniele, you came close to the right answer. The problem is that a standard VS 2013 installation doesn't install SQL server Express but only sql local express. When using sqlExpress in the connection string then closing and opening VS it complains there is no sql server express. I assumed localdb was a feature of sql server express and maybe I'm wrong and VS just gives that warning to confuse me even more.

Comment: HMR, I see, that makes sense.  Thanks for the additional info. It does sound like there is something else happening here.

Answer (score 1):

Just for chuckles instead of putting (localdb) put a period `'.'`. So that it would look like

```
Data Source=.\v11.0;
```

I'd be surprised if it works but you can do that in full SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is web site project you need to specify correct .net framework version to build. SqlLocalDb need .net framework 4.

If you create web project and add web site source files to it, it will work if the .net framework is 4+. When you open web site default target framework or existing dll framework may not be same and may be .net 3.5, that's why you get this error.

[image]

Comment: I did need to change target framework to 3.5 so tried a connection string like "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Products.mdf;Integrated Security=True;;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True" in the web.config but same error.

Comment: You were right about needing .net 4,0 for a connection string that uses (localDb). Since the project can't be built at all using .net 4.0 and the server uses .net 2.0 I've used named pipes to connect to localdb.

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of the reference System.Data between the empty project that works, and your project that does not work. You can use the solution explorer to check this. Are both projects using the same version?

[image]

Comment: Thank you; both projects are referencing the same dll: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll

Answer (score 0):

Also... this could be related to your setup in IIS.

Your website's (session state) could be setup to use SQL Server for your session. Check there too... I just had this issue, and realized our sqlbox connection changed and forgot to update on IIS.

Comment: This should be a comment (once you have [enough reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to add one) instead of an answer. Please refer to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) to learn how to earn reputation and therefore be able to comment.

Answer (score 0):

This error showed up after I compressed the **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA** directory.  Uncompressing it fixed the error.