# Can't Connect to Local SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

This:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\\Users\\Joe\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\FileIO\\FileIO\\Database.mdf';Integrated Security=True");
try
{
   myConnection.Open();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

Returns this error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Any Ideas?

Comment: Check http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/ and http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2340/resolving-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-errors/

Comment: Take a look here for all the help you need in creating a Connection String to a SQL Server Database http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: @JoeBabcock you can put an @ in front of the string a-la @"yourpathhere" that makes it a string literal, and you no longer need double back-slashes which makes it easier to... not forget to add them if you get what I mean

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the double backslash on the data source. It's reading the `\v` as a vertical tab.

Or you can use a leading `@` before the whole string to treat it as a verbatim string (if you do this then you'll need to clear out the extra backslashes on your filepath).

Answer (score 0):

(Copied from [error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924877/error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server/16050436#16050436))

The problem was related to the application not running in .net version 4.0

According to the following page:
http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012#sqlconnection

You need .net 4.0 and up to use named pipes:

> The Server=(localdb) syntax is not supported by .NET framework
>   versions before 4.0.2. However the named pipes connection will work to
>   connect pre 4.0.2 applications to LocalDB instances.

```
SqlLocalDB.exe create MyInstance
SqlLocalDB.exe start MyInstance
SqlLocalDB.exe info MyInstance
```

The info provides the named pipe then this can be used in the connection string:

```
<add name="conn" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
connectionString="Server=np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#B1704E69\tsql\query"/>
```