# Azure storage emulator cannot connect to LocalDB

Tags: azure, localdb, azure-storage-emulator

I have a problem with the Azure storage emulator, which refuses to connect to LocalDb. It used to work just fine before I created an ODBC connection to it using the named pipe. What happened:

- I needed to access the data in my database from Mathematica, so I generated an ODBC connection.
- ODBC could not connect to (localdb)\v11.0, so I used a named pipe instead.

Since then, Azure has stopped to work. I upgraded to SDK2.0, but it did not help. I tried to run DSInit.exe, but I get:

```
Found SQL Instance (localdb)\v11.0.
Creating database DevelopmentStorageDb20 on SQL instance '(localdb)\v11.0'.
Cannot create database 'DevelopmentStorageDb20' : A network-related or instance-specific
error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is
configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error
Locating Server/Instance Specified).

One or more initialization actions have failed. Resolve these errors before attempting to
run the storage emulator again. Please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=248088
for more details.
```

Do you have any idea what could I do to make it work again?