# Getting SQL Server error in ASP.net application when using different computer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple ASP.NET C# application which works fine on the computer it was created. However, whenever this project is compiled and run on any other computer, I get the following error:

`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)`

On the following line:

`bool admin = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin");`

I could previously run the application on a different computer without error. I have made no changes to any SQL server settings.

In Web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-INT422Project-20140320070224.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-INT422Project-20140320070224;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DataContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Lab5;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|INT422Project.mdf" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Please update the question to include the connection string. Do NOT include the password, replace it with something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Your better change your connection String value to use a real sql server database.

SQL Server Express or  LocalDB  is not used for production web applications because it is not designed to work with IIS.

Comment: This application is an academic assignment. The values in the Web.config file were provided by my instructor.

Comment: Ok then check this link  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gaurav/archive/2013/12/21/deployment-of-sql-express-localdb-on-iis.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following:

1. Make sure the sql server service is up and running.
2. Make sure the TCP/IP ports are enabled.

If both are fine, I would suggest you to read the servername and database name from the app.config/ web.config which makes life easier.

Comment: As this is just application for an academic assignment, I don't have any separate SQL server services running. It works fine on my computer which I originally created the application. However, it does not work on any other computer, even those with the exact same software.

Comment: ok as Damith mentioned..check the following link..http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gaurav/archive/2013/12/21/deployment-of-sql-express-localdb-on-iis.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Dude, Check this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16054490/3081461

you can read more about localdb at microsoft TechNet as well : 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

Comment: I don't understand why my application won't run on another computer with the exact same software as the one which works.